# What do you call it when for example, pizza hut asks for your zip code to determine your nearest pizza hut?

Tags: geolocation

I am trying to look up different examples of this specific action for a company; they're asking me to look up services that do this, yet I don't know how to look for it as I don't know what the action is called.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/

Comment: Finding out where a user is is called localization.

Comment: Localization typically refers more specifically to customizing the language and layout of a UI for a particular language and region.  Searching under localization is likely to produce lots of output that the person asking doesn't want, based on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall term for services related to a physical location is called [Geolocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation).

Searches on that term will turn up existing services and examples for that kind of thing.